# Big-$O$ of $ \log \binom{n}{n/2} $

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I'm asked to evaluate this: $ \mathcal{O} \bigg( \log_2 \binom{n}{n/2} \bigg) $.
I played with this a bit and I keep getting $\mathcal{O} (n\log n)$.

When I substitute $n! = \sqrt{2\pi n} \Big(\dfrac{n}{e}\Big)^n $ I get $\mathcal{O}(n)$, which is the correct answer.

Can you please tell me how to do it without using the above substitution?

Comment: Is your goal to make the "substitution" rigorous (e.g. using the precise statement of Stirling's approximation), or to do it without using Stirling at all?

Comment: You can also use the majoration of $\binom{n}{n/2}$ by $2^n$ (this is the sum of the $\binom{n}{k} $).

Comment: @NateEldredge without using Stirling. Stirling's formula is only an approximation, right? Is there any straightforward way to prove it?

Comment: @AltunHasanli: Well, it is an approximation, but there are theorems about how large the error in the approximation might be.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) has lots of results and references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I assume that $n=2k$.**

Note that $\log_2\binom{n}{n/2}=O\left(\log\binom{n}{n/2}\right)$ by the change-of-base formula for logarithms. Thus, we just need to show that $$\log\binom{n}{n/2}=O(n).$$ Using [Riemann-Stieltjes integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral), we can show that $$\log(n!)=\sum_{j=1}^n\log(j)=n\log n-n+O(\log n).\tag{1}$$
This is actually stronger than what we need; we only need that $\log(n!)=n\log n+O(n)$. As such, we'll use the weaker statement in what follows.

Using $(1)$, the definition of the binomial, and the property of logarithms that $\log(a/b)=\log(a)-\log(b)$, we can show that for $n=2k$, $$\log\binom{n}{n/2}=\log\left(\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}\right)=2k\log(2k)-2k\log(k)+O(k)=O(n).$$

Comment: Sorry, I’m not familiar with $\Theta(f(x))$ notation. Can you tell me the definition?

Comment: @Altun we aren’t ignoring anything. It is precisely that asymptotic that allows you to deduce the desired bound.

Comment: Also, just reading that link, I think it is clear the $O(f(x))$ and $\Theta(f(x))$ are not the same thing